# Local System Account and Windows Credential Manager

Tags: powershell

So, I have a powershell script that uses the Windows Credential Manager to store credentials. When I use my account I can access these credentials, but it seems like when I try to use the local system account (trying not to use my account to run scripts) it doesnt pull from the credential manager. What gives?

```
if (Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name CredentialManager) {
    Import-Module CredentialManager
}

else {
    Install-Module CredentialManager
}

$service_fqdn = '<SERVER-FQDN>'

$creds = Get-StoredCredential -Target '<SERVICE ACCOUNT>'
$oauth_client_id = $creds.UserName
$oauth_client_secret = $creds.GetNetworkCredential().Password
```

I get a null error when I try to get the password for $oauth_client_secret

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that all credentials are stored and accessible for *only* the **current logged in user**.

i.e. If you create the credential logged in as `user1`, you can't access them as `user2`, or even with the `Local System Account`.

> This makes sense, and can't be worked around. You don't want random
> logged in people/users to be able to access other people's
> credentials.

The "workaround" is to create a new user/service account with minimal permissions that is dedicated to running the service/script. You then can create the new credential as that new user/service account:

```
New-StoredCredential -Target "Server1" -Username "SA-Username" -Password "Password123"
```

Then running the script as that user, you will have access to the credential.

Note: you cannot use the [Local System Account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/localsystem-account) to run the script as you can't explicitly specify the Local System Account as a valid user to create the new stored credential.

Edit:

As @MrBungle correctly mentions. The [Local **System** Account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/localsystem-account) has god like powers, and it is recommended not to use it if possible. Instead use the unprivileged [Local **Service** Account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/localservice-account) whenever possible.

Comment: What would be your suggestion if I were using the credential store to keep an api id and key?

Comment: You have the right idea. The credential store is a good place for storing credentials (better than storing it in plain text files). The Local Service Account isn't necessarily the "best" account to use for running things (i.e. it has way more permissions than are actually needed) and that's why I recommend creating a new user account with minimal permissions that is dedicated to running the service/script. Not only can you use the Credential Manager for storing the credentials, you can limit access (e.g. deny interactive login), give crazy complex passwords etc. to further secure the account.

Comment: I don't find New-StoredCredential in any Powershell modules I have. Can you reference the module?

Comment: @JasonS The `New-StoredCredential` cmdlet is available from the [Credential Manager](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/CredentialManager) PowerShell module which has to be installed from the PowerShell Gallery. Using PowerShellGet, simply run: `Install-Module -Name CredentialManager`

Comment: Note there is a big different between the Local Service account and Local System account.  It is very much recommended to use the unpriviledged LocalService account wherever possible, rather than the god-like LocalSystem account.  This answer links to the LocalSystem account, but is referring to the LocalService account in the wording, and should be corrected.

Comment: @Mr.Bungle Thank you for pointing that out! I totally mixed up the Service/System wording. I have corrected the post.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere in Microsoft???